# seaborn pairplot after converting a integer column to string

Tags: python, seaborn

I am facing a trouble with seaborn.pairplot() with the below code

I have a dataframe and in one case I have to convert one of the column to string; After converting to String.
Pairplot() is not working properly.
How to fix the issue.

Below is the code,

```
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df_temp = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)

print(df_temp)

sns.pairplot(df_temp) # This works

# convert one of the column to String datatype
df_temp['A'] = df_temp['A'].astype(str)
sns.pairplot(df_temp) # Gives error
```

Complete error log - [Error log](https://gist.github.com/vamsigp/43b2ab9a41834cb0fcefe8dfd76c8112)

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. You can't produce a scatter with one of the two coordinates being a string. It's quite logic if it returns an error. What output would you like to have?

Comment: @Gio You can sure produce a scatter with strings. The question is if that is desired of course.

Comment: @Gio As i converted 'A' to string type i dont want 'A' in my pairplot.

Comment: @Vamsi, have a look at the answer. You can filter out all the columns which do not have a specific format (in this case I chose “float”) and then you simply plot the filtered dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the diagonal of a pairplot there are histograms. It is not possible to draw histrograms from strings. Since I'm not sure what you would want to show on the diagonal instead in such case, let's leave that out and simply plot a pair grid from the dataframe which contains strings in one column,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns


Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)
df['A'] = list("VWXYZ")

g = sns.PairGrid(df, vars=df.columns, height=2)
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead the aim is to just use numeric columns, you can filter the dataframe by dtype.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns

Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)


# convert one of the column to String datatype
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
sns.pairplot(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This helps. In my case i dont want to show 'A' at all. Your solution helps me for now. Thanks!

Comment: That wasn't clear. If you don't want to show `A` at all, there is no problem. Either select the columns to plot via the `vars`, `sns.pairplot(df_temp, vars=["B", "C", "D"])` or filter them out `sns.pairplot(df_temp[["B", "C", "D"]])`

Comment: In my case there are 40 columns, in those i have converted around 10 columns and if the number of columns changes or increases it difficult to exclude manually everytime. I thought if theres any other way to exclude such

Comment: Yeah, that was just to show you the principle. You can of course automate it. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df_temp = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)

print(df_temp)

# convert one of the column to String datatype
df_temp['A'] = df_temp['A'].astype(str)
```

You can find all the columns of type float and plot only those.

```
cols_to_plot=df_temp[df_temp.types=='float']#find not strings

sns.pairplot(df_temp[cols_to_plot[cols_to_plot==1].index])
```